# Get collection index to cycle back around

Tags: python, arrays, list, collections

When using a collection such as a python list, is there a way to make my index "continuous"? For example say I have the following list:

```
list=[0,1,2,3]
```

Now here `list[3]=3` but `list[4]` is not defined... is it possible to set up my collections so that they cycle back around, so that `list[4]=0, list[8]=0..., list[280]=0...`, even though my list still only carries those 4 elements?

Comment: You can use modulo arithmetic. for example: `lst[4 % len(lst)]`

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can do it. If you .init the class one time then the change will be done.

```
class list_no_stop(list):
  def __getitem__(self,i):
      return list(self)[i % len(self)]
  def __setitem__(self,x,i):
     nv=list(self)
     nv[x % len(self)]=i         
     self.clear()
     self.extend(nv)
newlist=list_no_stop([1,2,3,5])
print(newlist[100])
#print(newlist[11])
newlist[11]=80
#newlist[12]=1000

newlist[12]=1000
print(newlist)
```